# How to discard leftover challah

Tags: challah-shabbat-bread, bread, disposal

Is there a special way of discarding leftover bread/challah?

Comment: Savta, welcome to miyodeya.  A similar question was asked here: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/3235/throwing-out-bread-or-challah.  Please take notice of the red warning at the top of the page.

Comment: Savta, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish at http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login

Comment: Maybe you can indicate why you would think there should be a special method.

Comment: Not an answer to your question (so this is a comment), but when I have leftover bits of challah I let them dry and turn them into breadcrumbs for use in later cooking.  (Maybe not this month, though. :-) )

Comment: possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3235/759

Answer (score 4):

Feed it to the birds, or wrap it in a bag prior to throwing into the garbage.

http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5765/vayakhel.html

Comment: Link returns 500...

Comment: Can't make such a small edit, but the content from the currently-broken link in this answer can be found [here](http://gt.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5765/vayakhel.html). (Torah.org is apparently undergoing some extended update process, and much of their content is only available on the (relocated) older version of the site.)

Answer (score 1):

1) Eat it as is.

2) Eat it in some concoction. French toast is one possibility.

3) Why do you have leftovers in the first place? I think people should not buy excessive quantities that tend to can lead to such a situation ab initio (lechatechila). Doing so could possibly be a gram of bal tashchis (problem of being cause of wasting food indirectly).

4) Do not dump them on someone else's property or on public property to allegedly feed birds. Other people do not necessarily want pigeon encampments and what they leave behind. If you choose to do that, do it only on your own property.

Comment: I think he was asking if there is a special way to treat leftover bread, not for a lecture on Bal Tashchis or suggestions on ways to make the leftovers tasty. If he wanted to eat it as French Toast I'm sure he would. As Gershon notes below (http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6785/leftover-challah/6786#6786), it is appropriate to wrap it before putting it into the garbage.

Comment: @Seth J - I think it is safe to say "..._she_ was asking..." http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6534/false-portrayal-on-an-anonymous-qa-site

Comment: -1 It doesn't answer the intent of the question.  Furthermore, Challah which was on a table on which meat was served should NOT be eaten with dairy, so in most cases, French Toast is not an option for leftover challah.

Comment: I don't think answer 3 is helpful or even answers the question.  We frequently have guests over for Friday night and need to have enough challah for all.  But there is bound to be leftovers.  As SethJ put it, he was asking if there was a special way to treat leftover challah.