# Throwing Out Bread

Tags: halacha, bread, bal-tashchit-waste

What is the nature of the prohibition to destroy bread? Why is it commonly presented differently from other destruction (bal tashchit)?

Comment: How do you know there is such a prohibition?

Comment: @DoubleAA nonexistence is also a nature; i.e. if the answer is that there is no such prohibition, or that it is misrepresented, then that is the answer.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3235/throwing-out-bread-or-challah

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be an independent prohibition to throw out bread, and doing so could cause one to become poor (cf. Shabbos 143a, Tosfos to Brachos 52b) due to the respect and appreciation that we should have towards Hashem's sustenance that He has provided (cf. Aruch Hashulchan 180:4, Kaf HaHayyim 24:47-48). This rule-of not discarding bread with the rest of one's garbage-probably doesn't have to do with Val tashchis, because it applies only to pieces that are a kezayis or larger (Shulchan Aruch 180:4 though see Mishnah Berurah 180:10 for a stringency not to discard bread crumbs that would combine to be a kezayis).

Answer (score 0):

from: http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue6.pdf

> Bread may be used for any purpose as long as it is not used in a disrespectful manner and the bread will not be
>   ruined by what you are doing to it.7 One should not pass a cup of wine over a piece of bread because the wine
>   may fall on the bread and make it uneatable. Similarly, one should not place raw meat onto a piece of bread.8
>   One is allowed to use bread to cover food in a utensil, since this is not showing disrespect to the bread because
>   it will be eaten as part of the food.9 Accordingly, it is common for caterers to use a bread-like food to cover the
>   soup at weddings to retain the heat.10 When reciting kiddush one may place a siddur on top of the challah
>   cover.11 Similarly, one who wants to lift up a sefer may place bread underneath the sefer in order to lift it.12
>   When washing mayim achronim one should be careful not to let the water fall onto bread.13 Many caterers bake bread in a round shape, hollow the inside, and fill the space with soup (the bread is hard so no soup leaks
>   through). It would seem that if the people eat the bread (bowl) afterwards this may be permitted.14
>
> 7 Mesechtas Berochos 50b, Tosfas “ein zurkin,” Rosh 7:32, Shulchan
>   Aruch 171:1, Mishnah Berurah 171:2. See Biur Halacha 171 “lo.”
>
> 8 Refer
>   to Rashi Mesechtas Berochos ibid “ein,” Rabbeinu Yona, Rif page 37b,
>   Shulchan Aruch 171:1, Pri Megadim M.Z. 1, Mishnah Berurah 171:2, 5,
>   Kaf Ha’chaim 2.
>
> 9 Pri Megadim M.Z. 171:2, Mishnah Berurah 7.
>
> 10 Horav
>   Yisroel Belsky Shlita. Refer to Torah L’shma 106.
>
> 11 Birchos Hashem
>   3:17:footnote 62.
>
> 12 Eitz Hasadeh 17:footnote 8.
>
> 13 Kaf Ha’chaim
>   171:4.
>
> 14 Refer to Shulchan Aruch 171:3.

It would seem however that whether bread really has a unique status might be subject to a dispute amongst the rishonim. From http://halachayomit.co.il/EnglishDefault.asp?HalachaID=2821 :

> Regarding bread, however, the Rishonim disagree: According to the Tosafot, even if the bread will not become ruined as a result of throwing it, such as by throwing from side to side on a table, it is still forbidden to do so, for bread has a special significance and throwing is considered degrading towards it. The Rosh, Tur, and other great Rishonim rule likewise. (The commentary Tziyun Le’Nefesh Chaya, ibid, indeed infers this from the language of the Baraita.)
>
> On the other hand, the Rashba and Rabbeinu Yonah (quoted by the Bet Yosef in Chapter 171) write that there is no distinction between bread and other foods and as long as the food is not ruined by throwing it, it is permissible to do so.

As far as why we would treat bread differently from other foods (assuming that is indeed the case) - I assume it has to do with the religious significance of bread in *halacha* (as seen in it's roles in the *avodah* e.g. in the *menachot, lechem hapanim, shtei halechem*, etc.) and the fact that it is representative of food in general (which is presumably why the *hamotzi* blessing exempts the *brachot* of all other items eaten as part of the meal, i.e.: with the bread). Also, I believe there may be midrashic/kabbalistic analogies between man and bread.

Comment: This would serve to prove that such a prohibition exists. But the OP wants an understanding to the nature of this prohibition. I.E. why it exist specifically for bread.

Comment: This discusses *throwing* bread. I asked about throwing *out* bread.

Comment: @mevaqesh I think that he is answering "Why is it presented differently from other destruction" under "bread really has a unique status". How else is bread different from other destruction? (If not respect)